# Which statistical Test for correlation between metric groups

Tags: r, testing, regression, anova, canonical-link

I´m quite new to Statistics and R, so I have to write my bachelor thesis till December and my tests were all wrong, so I´d be happy if you could help me: 
I want to analyse if there´s a connection between the stage of age of the animal and the place where it occurs. The thing is that the places I researched have different size so I had to change this and got now a table like this :

```
Adulti/Place1, Subadulti/Place1, Young/Place1, Adulti/Place2, Subadulti/Place2, Young, Place2,... 
0.00357        0                 0.00247         0            0                 0.024
0              0.234              0.0040        0.0032         0                0
```

each row shows the number of animals at one age stage per m²of the place. 
I´m not sure how I can work with this :(

Is an anova the suitable choice? I also heard of the canonical regression, but I´m not sure if this might work. I´d be really happy for any help!

Best Greetings from Germany, 
Lea :)

Comment: Asking for help choosing a statistical test is off topic for Stack Overflow. Instead you should ask at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic.

Comment: echoing @MrFlick that this is not the best portal for this type of question but just wanted to direct you that you can do ANOVA comparing the stage of animals between groups (places). This is based on two sentences you wrote here where the actual model can turn up to be different if you provide more information in  https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you both for your information ! :) I´m going  to go ask again at the cross validated site mr flick wrote, to get more details, but also thank you for the further answer @VitaliAvagyan! :)